# what is info-mode-hook

Tags: hooks, info

I am trying to rebind some keys for `info-mode` without success. I am not sure whether I am missing something, or whether a special hook is required. I am using the following hook in my `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'info-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (message "setting up info-mode")
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c l")
                           'info-last)
            (local-set-key (kbd "g g")
                           'evil-goto-first-line)
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c g")
                           'info-goto-node)
            )
 )
```

But when I run `C-h i` to open `info-mode`, my custom bound keys above do not work and I do not get any message like "setting up info-mode`in my`Messages` buffer.

I have evaluated the above hook with an empty emacs config (`emacs -q`), and I have many other mode hooks that are working fine.

Any suggestions to help troubleshoot or resolve this issue would be appreciated! I am happy to clarify anything as well.

Comment: Try using a capital "I" for "Info-mode . . . " -- e.g., `Info-mode`; `Info-mode-hook`.  It's unfortunate that the author decided to break from tradition with lowercase letters, but that's how it goes sometimes.  To see more, type:  `M-x find-library RET info RET`  Some of the variables/functions are lowercase -- it's a hodge-podge mess if you ask me.

Comment: Yep, that works! If you add your comment as an answer, I will happily accept it :D

Comment: Take note that `C-h v major-mode` would tell you `Info-mode`, and that mode hooks are always the mode name with a `-hook` suffix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in `Info-mode` uses a combination of initial uppercase and/or all lowercase letters for the various variables/functions/faces.  There may be a rhyme or reason, but it quite frankly escapes me as I read through the source-code.  I wish there were a better method than familiarizing ourselves with the source code by typing `M-x find-library RET info RET` and reading through it with some targeted word searches, but I don't really have a better method -- except perhaps `find-variable`/`find-function`/`find-face` and trying both `info-` with a lowercase and `Info-` with an uppercase.

In the context of this particular question, the major-mode is `Info-mode` with a capital letter "I" and the hook is similar -- i.e., `Info-mode-hook` with a capital "I".

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully someone in the future will find this very helpful.